# Bootstrap- How to style a <select>?

Tags: php, html

So I'm trying to style the select tag using bootstrap, but this is the output that I'm getting.. [https://ibb.co/iyycak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD2cG.jpg)
And this is how I want it to look like.. [https://ibb.co/eMkC85](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ1YG.jpg)

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<label for="orderReasonCode">Order Reason :</label>&nbsp;
<select class="form-control" name="orderReasonCode" id="orderReasonCode" title="Order reason" data-width="250px">
<?php echo getTableDD($DB->pre . "order_reason", "orderReasonCode", "orderReasonName", $_POST['orderReasonCode']); ?>
                            </select>
```

Comment: You should start reading the [doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#selects) .

Comment: looks like you haven't included bootstrap in your page. make sure you have jquery, bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css linked properly.

Comment: @Elie.. It's all there man.

Comment: that's weird could you add a working example on fiddle?